# How to move a CSS class below another?

Tags: css, css-position

On http://www.csszengarden.com/ how can I move classes (which contain headings and paragraphs) around?

**The current order is:**

- **explanation**
- participation
- benefits
- requirements

**I want:**

- participation
- benefits
- **explanation**
- requirements

It should keep the structure with any screen resolution, as it does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do it other than using `position: absolute` and manually placing it on the page.

That may be pretty impractical, depending on what you're trying to do.

It's totally doable with Javascript but that's not what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking because I'm trying to move content around in a WordPress plugin I've developed.

I don't want to use the 'position: absolute' tag because I want the format to be flexible for different resolutions, custom user fonts, themes, etc.

I thought it would be possible with CSS, but maybe not. I may have to look at a Javascript  solution instead. Thanks.

Comment: Javascript is usually the best solution for that kind of thing.  If you're using a CSS framework, it may have a way to reposition elements to some extent.  I haven't used it in a while, but I recall that Grid 960 could do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that flexbox has an `order` property, which lets you order your flex items.

For more information, see the specification at http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#order-property

Note, the flexbox layout module is an Editor's Draft. It might not work as intended in all available browsers, especially in older browsers.